# How to Analyze and Document a SQL Server Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, application-design, documentation

I have been handed a large SQL Server batch process containing <100 stored procedures and functions. There is no documentation, I cannot rely on comments.

High level, what are the best practices to efficiently document the logic and data flow?

Can anyone point me to documentation, tools or other guidance?

EG: One process is an ETL that imports text files to tables, massages the data then loads target tables.   This ETL spans 2 dbs, about 20 procs/functions and 20 or so tables.  Probably <5000 lines of code. (Its pretty gnarly)

I need to become SME on this bad boy.  In the past it has been hunt and peck, walking the code chunk by chunk.  There must be a better way.

Comment: [DOC xPress](https://www.sentryone.com/products/doc-xpress/sql-metadata-management) (soon to be [SentryOne Document](https://docs.sentryone.com/help/sentryone-document)) might be worth a look. *Disclaimer: I work for SentryOne.*

Comment: Thanks!!! I watch your videos n stuff all the time.